# Dynamic Crosstab Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, pivot-table, crosstab

I have a problem when switching from SQL Server to MySQL with Crosstab Query.

Suppose that I have a table like this:

```
| ID | BANKID | 1MONTH |        3MONTHS |        6MONTHS |       10MONTHS |       12MONTHS | 18MONTHS |       24MONTHS |       30MONTHS |       36MONTHS |
|----|--------|--------|----------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|----------|----------------|----------------|----------------|
|  1 |      1 |      3 | 2.900000095367 | 2.799999952316 | 2.700000047684 | 2.599999904633 |      2.5 | 2.400000095367 | 2.299999952316 | 2.200000047684 |
|  2 |      2 |      5 | 4.900000095367 | 4.800000190735 | 4.699999809265 | 4.599999904633 |      4.5 | 4.400000095367 | 4.300000190735 | 4.199999809265 |
```

I would like to display it like this:

```
BankID           1          2
1 Month          3          5
3 Months         2.9        4.9
6 Months         2.8        4.8
10 Months        2.7        4.7
12 Months        2.6        4.6
18 Months        2.5        4.5
24 Months        2.4        4.4
30 Months        2.3        4.3
36 Months        2.2        4.2
```

How can I create this kind of crosstab in MySQL?

You can test data at here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cf88/1

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Use Following Query

```
Set @Sq = NUll;
Set @S =Null;
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(CASE WHEN id = ',
      BankID,' THEN val end) AS "',
      BankID,'"')

    )
into @Sql
FROM
  bankdeposit;


SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'select id, ''',
      c.column_name,
      ''' as Bankid, ',
      c.column_name,
      ' as val 
      from bankdeposit'
    ) SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
  ) into @xSq
FROM information_schema.columns c
where c.table_name = 'bankdeposit'
  and c.column_name not in ('id','BankID',
 'CreateDate', 'CreateBy', 'ModifyDate', 'ModifyBy',
 'totalLoan','TotalDeposit','EstablishedYear','NumberOfStore')
order by c.ordinal_position;


SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'select id, ''',
      c.column_name,
      ''' as Bankid, ',
      c.column_name,
      ' as val 
      from bankdeposit'
    ) SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
  ) into @S
FROM information_schema.columns c
where c.table_name = 'bankdeposit'
  and c.column_name in ('totalLoan','TotalDeposit',
  'EstablishedYear','NumberOfStore' )
order by c.ordinal_position;


select CONCAT('select Bankid,',@sql,' from(select id, Bankid, val
           from
           (', @xSq,',',@S,') x  order by id) xx group by Bankid 
           order by length(BankID),BankID');

PREPARE stmt FROM @xSq;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[Sql Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cf88/17)

Comment: Hi Sathish, I input this query into my real database but it's not working (my real database has more column than this). it causes error when UNION ALL Block.

it said that "[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'". 

Please check it here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa1a9/1

Comment: that table have id column  @Pengan

Comment: @Pengan Check this Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa1a9/14.  you give  ignore columns name in `c.column_name not in ('id','BankID')`

Comment: Hi, Sathish, Sorry to bother you again. I would like to display all columns except 'CreateDate', 'CreateBy', 'ModifyDate', 'ModifyBy' Then I put this into Query "c.column_name not in ('id','BankID')". However when I input this, it said that in correct syntax near "'c.column_name not in ('id','BankID')' at line 1: c.column_name not in ('id','BankID')". 

Can you help me to fix this?

Very thank you for your helpfullness!

Please check this link at : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa1a9/20

Comment: @Pengan check my query. Now am change it.try and tell

Comment: Finally,I solved it. Thank Sathish, your query is correct since from the beginning however the error is that MySQL has limit char to 1M only (max_allowed_packet). That's why it cause error.