# How to convert result value in column name using query?

Tags: mysql, join

I have one view which contains following fields:

[image: Parent table]

I got following result using following query:

```
select `key`,fieldvalue  FROM page_view WHERE language = 'EN' AND page_flag = 'imprint'
```

and got following result:

[image: result which i am getting]

But i want above result in such a way so that i can use record as follows because i dont want to retrieve via loop:

```
title      link      dmeta    kmeta      content
imprint    imprint   --       --         --
```

So that i can access it via

```
$result['title'],$result['link']...
```

Comment: The result you are getting is in correct format. you can access it the way you require

Comment: no i cant use that way because it gives $result['key'] = title $result['fieldvalue'] = imprint in loop

Comment: you need to do pivot on table, example in mysql is hehe [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: Here is a link that you can use to do in a dynamic way: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47902/how-to-transpose-convert-rows-as-columns-in-mysql

Comment: yes it helpful let me see

Comment: see also [mysql dynamic crosstab query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34206766/mysql-dynamic-crosstab-query-selecting-child-records-as-additional-columns/34237336#34237336)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this with array to get this kind of functionality:

```
$q = $this->db->query('SELECT `key`,fieldvalue 
                                FROM page_view
                                WHERE page_flag = ? AND language = ?',array($page_flag,$language));
        if($q->num_rows() >0)
        {
            $result = array();
            $r = $q->result_array();
            foreach($r as $field)
            {
                $result[$field['key']] = $field['fieldvalue'];
            }
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($result);

        }
```

Above code will give output as i want using query:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Imprint
    [link] => imprint
    [dmeta] => meta description
    [kmeta] => keywords
    [content] =>Impressum
)
```