# MySQL - Pivoting subsequent rows with CASE - can only get first row

Tags: mysql

**What I'm Trying To Do**

I have a table called episodes, episodes have none to multiple related links referenced in another table called related_links. I need to move all of the related links into the episodes table per episode row respectively.  So one episode may have 1 related link whereas another episode may have 5 related links and I need a column for each related link per episode row. The max amount of related links one of the episodes has is 24.

Hopefully that made sense, but I'll try to diagram it:

*episodes* table:

```
id    title
--    -----------
1     ep title 1
2     ep title 2
```

*related_links* table:

```
object_id    display_text      url
---------    ------------      ----------------
1            text 1            1.com
1            text 2            2.com
1            text 3            3.com
2            text 4            4.com
```

Outcome I'm looking for in the episodes table:

```
id     title         dtxt1    url1    dtxt2    url2    dtxt3    url3              
--     ----------    -----    -----   -----    ----    -----    ----
1      episode 1     text 1   1.com   text 2   2.com   text 3   3.com 
2      episode 2     text 4   4.com
```

**What I've Tried**

```
SELECT 
    episodes.id AS episode_id,
    episodes.title AS episode_title,
    CASE
        WHEN related_links.display_text LIKE '%' THEN related_links.display_text
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'dtxt1',
    CASE
        WHEN related_links.url LIKE '%' THEN related_links.url
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'url1'
FROM
    episodes
        INNER JOIN
    related_links ON related_links.object_id = episodes.id
```

Which is close and results in:

```
id     title         dtxt1    url1                 
--     ----------    -----    -----   
1      episode 1     text 1   1.com   
2      episode 2     text 4   4.com
```

But it only pulls in the first related display_text and url for an episode. I'm not sure how to manually or dynamically repeat it for each subsequent related link.

Thanks for taking a look!

**Edit** - I've added an SQLfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a218f/1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL dynamic crosstab query: Selecting child records as additional columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34206766/mysql-dynamic-crosstab-query-selecting-child-records-as-additional-columns)